# Добавление нескольких значений в базу данных

Tags: python, django

Есть форма, которая после заполнения добавляет данные в базу:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ("url",)
        widgets = {
            'url': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':120,})   } 

            
    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        x = str(url).split()
        y = []
        for i in range(len(x)):
            z = x[i]
            y.append(z)
        print(y)
        return y
```

Если ввести несколько значений в форму одновременно, например:

```
1
2
3
```

то они сохранятся в базе данных как одна запись:

```
[1, 2 ,3]
```

Мне нужно чтобы каждое значение сохранялось как отдельная запись в базе данных.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Одна ModelForm предполагает работу с одной моделью. Вывод: либо использовать несколько форм (formset_factory), либо  переписать метод save так, как вы хотите, чтобы сохранялось

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы это делать, пользуйтесь не списками, а именно базами данных - SQLite3 и т.п. Чтобы сделать без базы данных (как делаете вы), попробуйте использовать словарь.